# Runtime error with no apparent cause

Tags: file-io, runtime-error, freepascal

I'm working with files in free pascal and I'm trying to open a file, but if it doesn't exists then I create it.

This is my code:

```
program messages;

const PATH_ = 'data/messages/';

type messageFields = 
        record
            date : String
          ; viewed : Boolean
          ; text : String
          ; sender : String [ 8 ]
      end
  ; messagesFile = file of messageFields 
  ;

procedure openMessagesFile ( var _file: messagesFile; _fileName: String; var error: Boolean );
  begin
    error := false;
    assign ( _file, PATH_+_fileName );
    {$I-}
    reset ( _file );
    {$I+}   
    if ( ioResult <> 0 ) then
      error := true;
  end;

var _file: messagesFile
  ; fileName: String
  ; error: boolean;
begin
  readln(filename);
  openMessageFile(_file, filename, error);
  if ( error ) then
    rewrite(_file);
end.
```

The first time that I execute the program, since the file doesn't exists, throw me an exception.
The second time, works fine!

This is the exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred at $00401759 :
EInOutError : Access denied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you reproduced this error with the exact code you've posted and I really can't see it causing the error you're getting. I cannot reproduce it and since you haven't included uses SysUtils you should get Runtime error 5 instead of EInOutError.

One thing that's terribly wrong with your code is that you're not closing the file after opening/creating it (although OS usually cleans it up after program finishes). Given this and the fact that you're getting EInOutError instead of Runtime error 5 I believe that your (real, bigger) program keeps the file open after creating it and trying to open it later, but fails since the file is already opened. The second time you run the program the file is already created so it's only opened once (for reading).

Comment: I think if the OS returns an error on the reset, it is not opened, and thus shouldn't be closed?

Comment: You're right. I know I'm making a lot of assumptions here, but I suspect that he only shows part of his original program and if I understand him correctly, the file gets created during the first execution although an exception is thrown. This makes me think that whatever causes the exception actually comes after the rewrite call (in his real code). Since his code here doesn't close the file after rewrite then his real code might not do it either and he may attempt to do something he cannot do in a "rewrite mode". So as a first step I would make sure that his not missing a CloseFile somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The code is a bit atypical, but Windows is known to keep fleeting locks on files for a few seconds even after they are closed and Dos originating code like this might suffer from that.

Maybe using FPC's FileExist() directly works better (IIRC on windows it is findfirst based, and not createfile based)